# Calling an instance method or a class method

Tags: ruby

I have a class:

```
Class Temp
  def Temperature
   puts "It's hot"
  end
end
```

I can call an instance of that:

```
mytemp = Temp.new
```

I can call the method `Temperature` on it. How do I know if I am calling an instance class or class methods?

Comment: What is an instance class?

Comment: Your code is invalid.

Comment: The *real* answer is, of course, that there are no class methods in Ruby. Ruby has only one kind of methods: instance methods. The *real* question then becomes, in *what class* are the methods defined, and *what instance* are you calling them on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets define following class. I defined methods beginning with lowercase as everybody does.

```
class Temp
  def temperature
   puts "I am instance"
  end

  def self.temperature
   puts "I am class"
  end
end
```

---

```
t = Temp.new
t.temperature
```

-> "I am instance"

---

```
Temp.temperature
```

-> "I am class"

---

```
t = Temp.new
t.class.temperature
```

-> "I am class"

Hope it helps and makes things clear :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you need to call `.new` to instantiate the class, `Temperature` is an instance method. You define class methods by appending a `self` to the method name - `def self.Temperature`. Then you'd call it without instantiating the class: `Temp.Temperature`.